# Rails table without primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a question about Rails. I have a table in my database without primary key with these columns - person_id, year, salary. My problem is when I want to edit one of the salary. I can't understand how to do it. That's my code:

Salaries controller:

```
def index
    @salaries = Salary.all
end

def edit
    @salary = Salary.find_by_person_id_and_year(params[:person_id], params[:year])
    @people = Person.all
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @salaries.each do |salary| %>
    <b><%= salary.person.Name %></b>
    <b><%= salary.Year %></b>
    <b><%= salary.Amount %></b>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_salary_path(salary.person_id, salary.year)%>
<% end %>
```

So, I add this to my routes.rb:

```
get 'salaries/index', :to => 'salaries#index',:as => 'salaries'
get 'salaries/:person_id/:year', :to => 'salaries#show', :as => 'salary'   
get 'salaries/new/:person_id/:year', :to => 'salaries#edit', :as => 'new_salary'
get 'salaries/edit/:person_id/:year', :to => 'salaries#edit', :as => 'edit_salary'
put 'salaries/:person_id/:year', :to => 'salaries#update'
post 'salaries/:person_id/:year', :to => 'salaries#create'
delete 'salaries/:person_id/:year', :to => 'salaries#destroy'
```

but I have these error message in my _form.html.erb: "undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass" on this line: <%= form_for(@salary) do |f| %>

```
def edit
    @person_id = params[:person_id]
    @year = params[:year]
    @salary = Salary.find_by_person_id_and_year(params[:person_id], params[:year])
    @people = People.all
end

def update
    @people = People.all
    @salary = Salary.new(params[:salary])
    if @salary.save
        flash[:success] = "Successfully edited salary"
        redirect_to salaries_path
    else
        @title = "Edit salary"
        render 'edit'
    end
end

_form.html.erb

<%= form_for(@salary, :url => salaries_path(:person_id => @person_id, :year => @year)) do |f|   %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails routing will automatically be looking for the id, so you will need to customise your routes.

For example, instead of `resources :salaries` in config/routes.rb try something like:

```
get 'salaries/index', :to => 'salaries#index',:as => 'salaries'
get 'salaries/edit/:person_id/:year', :to => 'salaries#edit', :as => 'edit_salaries'
put 'salaries/:person_id/:year', :to => 'salaries#update'
```

With other routes as you need such as:

```
get 'salaries/index', :to => 'salaries#index',:as => 'salaries'
get 'salaries/:person_id/:year', :to => 'salaries#show', :as => 'salary'
get 'salaries/new/:person_id/:year', :to => 'salaries#edit', :as => 'new_salary'
get 'salaries/edit/:person_id/:year', :to => 'salaries#edit', :as => 'edit_salary'
put 'salaries/:person_id/:year', :to => 'salaries#update'
post 'salaries/:person_id/:year', :to => 'salaries#create'
delete 'salaries/:person_id/:year', :to => 'salaries#destroy'
```

And the form:

```
form_for(@salary, :url => salary_path(:person_id => X, :year => Y)) do |f|
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but its strange that now  I have this error message in  my _form.html.erb: "undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass" on this line: <%= form_for(@salary) do |f| %>

Comment: You'll need to change the form_for slightly to cope with the difference from convention: form_for(@salary, :url => salaries_path(:person_id => X, :year => Y)) do |f| with your parameters as needed

Comment: Okay, but why now isn't working saving to the db when a call update or create. My url is http://0.0.0.0:3000/salaries/index?year=2013 and there is not update in my db

Comment: I did it but it still doesn't work. Edited my post with all my code.

Comment: What happens with salary_path instead of salaries_path in the :url=> ?

Comment: I have an error when I click edit: No route matches {:controller=>"salaries", :action=>"show", :person_id=>nil, :year=>"2013"}

Comment: Actually, I do not have show method in Salaries controller because I display that information in the profile of every person.

Comment: Busy day today - I should be able to help more tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

If you can add an additional ID column to the salaries table, you can use standard rails functions, like

```
(in app/models/person.rb)

class Person
  has_many :salaries
  has_one :current_salary, :class_name => "Salary", 
          :conditions => lambda { {:year => Time.now.year} }
  # outer curlies are for the lambda, inner curlies are for it to return a hash
end

(in config/routes.rb)


resources :people do
  resources :salaries
end
```

Then use normal access by ID

Comment: Yes, I can do it by adding primary key in my table but I don't want. Is is possible to do it without this new column?